# Align a link and button on the same line in CSS

Tags: css

I have a link and a button, each in their own div, and then wrapped in a shared div.  The link is centered on the page, and the button is aligned to the right side of the page.  I want to keep this, but have the two items on the same line.  How can I do this?[image: layout of buttons]

Comment: Please provide your HTML so we can see what kind of changes are needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use floats on your divs, something like this:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="center">
        center
    </div>
    <div class="right">
       right
    </div>
</div>
```

and for css:

```
.wrapper {
     width: 100%;
}

.center {
    float: left;
    margin-left: 50%;
}

.right {
    float: right;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/uK5hM/

Comment: Doesn't that align the left side of the center text to the center of the screen? I think OP wants the center of the center text to be in the center.

Comment: Agreed... was just hoping to get him on track since there is a lack of code and/or more information.